# write data into specific position in text file

Tags: vb.net

I need to write in an existing text file at 30th position. I am using seek but not working. using below code. Using Startposition as 30.

```
Public Sub WriteToFile(ByVal data As DataTable, ByVal FileName As String, ByVal FieldLength As String, ByVal StartPosition As String)
        Dim sbColumnData As New StringBuilder

        Using writer = New StreamWriter(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\test.txt")
            For Each oRecord In data.Rows
                sbColumnData.Clear()
                If oRecord(0).ToString().Length < FieldLength Then
                    sbColumnData.Append(oRecord(0).ToString().PadRight(FieldLength))
                ElseIf oRecord(0).ToString().Length = FieldLength Then
                    sbColumnData.Append(oRecord.ToString())
                Else
                    sbColumnData.Append(oRecord.ToString().Substring(0, FieldLength))
                End If
                writer.Seek(0, StartPosition )

                writer.WriteLine(sbColumnData)
                writer.Flush()
            Next

        End Using

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. Try:

```
writer.Seek(StartPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin)
writer.Write(sbColumnData, 0, sbColumnData.Length);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396